# When a php file is processed via Nginx & php-fpm, who owns the process ? NGINX or PHP-FPM?

Tags: php, apache, web, nginx, server

My PHP-FPM runs as user **www-data** and Nginx server runs as user **nginx**. I am trying to browse a file that is written in php e.g example.com/index.php.

So when php-fpm executes the index.php in the server who owns the process Nginx or php-fpm ?

I had read somewhere Nginx passes the php file to fast-cgi server, fast-cgi server runs the php file and generates the HTML content and send back to NGINX and NGINX again send back to the browser.

So according to me as Nginx is the parent process of fast-cgi process, Nginx should be the owner of the process. Please correct me if I am wrong.

**Update-1** ( Some more questions if my presumption is true )

1- Why people are more concern about what permission should be given to a NGINX user rather than PHP-FPM user ? Here is one of my related question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477389/is-it-okay-to-give-permission-of-rwx-to-my-php-user-outside-of-web-root

2- After Nginx decides that is is a PHP file, it gives it to the PHP interpreter. What does it mean by "GIVES" ? Does nginx process call php process and pass the 'path to file'? Or Nginx itself access the content of that php file and sends every code line by line to PHP-FPM ? In which format Nginx receives the output from the php interpreter ? Does it generate a temporary html file ?

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right afaik. Please refer to this website :

https://stillat.com/blog/2014/04/02/how-does-php-work-with-the-web-server-and-browser

which contains this simple picture to demonstrate how things work between A web server ( Apache / NginX etc ) with a interpreter ( PHP )

[image]

and you might ask , i asked for PHP-FPM ! well it doesn't matter in this scenario.

PH-FPM stands for : The PHP Fast Process Manager is a Fast-CGI handler for PHP scripts and applications.

so the priorities between Web server and php will be the same.

Comment: Thanks for a fast response. I have updated my question. Can you please check that?

Comment: This website doesn't give any deep inside. Well again here is the to the point question ? It is written "After Apache decides that is is a PHP file, it gives it to the PHP interpreter" . Can you tell me what it mean by "GIVES" ? Does nginx process call php process and pass the 'file path'  ?